# How to get this child component to render with view router in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

When a user logs in they are directed to LoggedIn.vue

This component has a child component called TasksActions.vue which I also want to render.  I get no errors but the child, TasksActions.vue does not render.

Routes.js

[image]

LoggedIn.vue

[image]

TasksActions.vue

[image]

Comment: You should be posting code instead of pictures, for apparent reasons. Also you are defining multiple components on the same path. The way it looks like is that your component is on `/taskactions` but you give no indication what you are actually seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never specified, are you actually directing the user to /taskactions at any point?

You can do this programmatically if needed as well:

```
this.$router.push({name: 'taskactions'});
```

Comment: yes it turned out that i was pushing to the parent expecting the child to just render as part of the page.  I didn't realise I had to push to the child.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the problem is you have two routes with the same path value `/` and the first one gets precedence and since it doesn't have any child component, you don't see anything there.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try like this:

```
{
  path: '/loggedin',
  component: LoggedIn,
  redirect: '/loggedin/taskactions'
  children: [
    path: 'taskactions',
    ...
  ]
}
```